Mantras for the peace of mind
When I try to sleep I am unable to sleep but feel very tired and want to sleep. Is there any mantras so that my mind can have some intense peace and rest to work for the next day? What are some mantras given in Hindu scriptures for getting rest of mind quickly? Thank you.

The Pranava and Harinam are some of the Mantras which can definitely grant peace of mind quickly and much more when chanted regularly.. Early to bed, sattvic food, avoiding bad association (kusanga) and remaining in good association (satsanga) also make a big difference for peace of mind.

Choose any Mantra of a deity you like that is also nice sounding, repeat it aloud multiple times eyes closed with low voice volume.
